# escaping apostrophes with parameter query not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to prevent from having to escape apostrophes in my string variables by using a parameterized query with a OleDbConnection, but it is not working. any help would be appreciated. I am trying to insert into an Access db and I keep getting those pesky html codes.

Any hep would be appreciated.

```
Dim pConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
pConn = New OleDbConnection(cb.ConnectionString)

Dim SqlString As String = "INSERT INTO Strings (Mlt_String_ID, Lng_ID, Strg_Name, Sht_Text, Lng_Text, Alt_Text) Values (@Mlt_String_ID,@Lng_ID,@Strg_Name,@Sht_Text,@Lng_Text,@Alt_Text)"

Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, pConn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mlt_String_ID", Mlt_String_ID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lng_ID", Lng_ID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Strg_Name", Strg_Name)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sht_Text", Sht_Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lng_Text", Lng_Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alt_Text", Alt_Text)

    pConn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    pConn.Close()
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

ou didn't describe what "not working" means.  Can you provide more information?  Are you getting an exception?  What is the exception and stack trace?

In any event, the OleDb commands do not support named parameters.  Use question marks instead:

```
Dim SqlString As String = "INSERT INTO Strings (Mlt_String_ID, Lng_ID, Strg_Name, Sht_Text, Lng_Text, Alt_Text) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

And the parameters must be added in order.

Comment: My apoloigies, the inserts are working, from my post I mentioned the results are the pesky html codes. "The representations of special characters." I have tried (?,?,?,?,?) but recently added the field names to see if that made a difference. I will retest though for certainty, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Just as a note the degree symbol in front of a capital C or F for temperture appears as follows: &#176;F. &#176; obviously represents the small circle indicating degree. I believe all parameters are added in order. The retest did not work, same results as noted in this post.